# passing data to another module component from other modules component which is not having child parent relation

Tags: angular

I am having core module which having component headbar ,there headbar if admin login the name should be appear ,so what I am asking that I need to set property **adminName** of that header span, but i am having modal which is in another component of different  module Home.module.ts .

what I want that when user clicks in login the admin name from that component should go to the headbar component ,I cant use @output property since these component not having the child=parent relation ,how can i notify change to another component I tried using component as provider in constructor function but change detection not happening.`enter code here`

Comment: use local storage or session storage

Comment: Read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I am trying to make understand that how my home component will notify to headbar component to set that in header-component because page wont be refreshed ,and i need to display that in header component no lifecycle  hook is going on.

Comment: You can use a service to do that. [The documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) talks about communication between a parent and a child but a service can transfer information to components anywhere in the application.

Comment: @cannors , service can transfer data i can pass ,but the problem is page wont be refreshed so ngoninit wont be fired neither constructor will be called so how can i set data to that header without any component life cycle hook.

Comment: The component subscribes to the service in the constructor or in `ngOnInit`, and it gets notified later. The callback is executed when the component is notified by the service, not when you subscribe to the service and not in an event of the component lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
has a section titled "Parent and children communicate via a service"
which shows the use of an rxjs Subject.

This is good information, and will work if the two components that need to communicate exist at the same time, e.g. they have a parent-child relationship, and both are instantiated before either sends a message.

This may work for you. However, if you wind up with additional components that need the same information, and they are not part of the parent-child relationship, then you can replace the Subject in the service with a BehaviorSubject. The BehaviorSubject always returns the last item upon subscription.

Note that your service would need to be a singleton (provided from the application module) so that all components get injected with the same instance of the service.